# Function error – postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I created this function that checks that total cost of a flight has been calculated correctly. It should multiply the price of seats e.g. 400 by the number of seats a customer has asked for e.g. 2. If the customer inputs the total correctly e.g.800 it should return the query successfully. If they don't input the total correctly e.g. 1000 then it should raise the exception 'price has been calculated incorrectly'.

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_totalcost() RETURNS trigger AS $check_totalcost$
    DECLARE seatprice int;
    DECLARE noofseats int;
    BEGIN
        SELECT priceperseat INTO seatprice
        FROM flight
        WHERE flightid = flightid;

        SELECT numseats INTO noofseats
        FROM flightbooking
        WHERE flightid = flightid;

        IF(seatprice*noofseats != new.totalcost) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'price has been calculated incorrectly';

        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $check_totalcost$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    /* This is used to run the function above */
    CREATE TRIGGER insert_totalcost
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON flightbooking
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_totalcost();
```

When I input the total incorrectly, it raises the exception which is what I want but when I input the total correctly, it also raises the exception when it should return the query successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queries

```
SELECT priceperseat INTO seatprice
FROM flight
WHERE flightid = flightid;

SELECT numseats INTO noofseats
FROM flightbooking
WHERE flightid = flightid;
```

make little sense as the conditions are always true. 
I guess you want to get `flightid` from inserted/updated record. Use the special record `NEW`:

```
WHERE flightid = NEW.flightid;
```

---

You have one more logical error in your function. The number of seats also should be got from the `new` record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_totalcost() 
RETURNS trigger AS $check_totalcost$
    DECLARE seatprice int;
    BEGIN
        SELECT priceperseat INTO seatprice
        FROM flight
        WHERE flightid = new.flightid;

        IF seatprice * new.numseats != new.totalcost THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'price has been calculated incorrectly';

        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
    $check_totalcost$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: When I put new in front of flightid, my trigger overall doesn't work. When I insert a flightbooking with the wrong total cost, it will insert it

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked and was very helpful.